# touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event doesn't get called

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

i am making a cocos2d game and i can't get the `touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to be called. Is there something i should do besides including this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using cocos2d with touches you should use the following methods instead

```
- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
```

Comment: figured it out.. the touch wasn't enabled `self.isTouchEnabled = YES;`

Comment: i didn't even know that property)